# Expected non-nullable type String! not to be null at value.workspaceSlug

Tags: heroku, prisma

The full issue :
Variable "$input" got invalid value {"workspaceSlug":null,"clusterName":"default","serviceName":"default","stageName":"default"}; Expected non-nullable type String! not to be null at value.workspaceSlug.

when I commanded git push heroku master.

I was struggling to find where is workspaceSlug value in prisma settings page but it was already in content and even couldn't be changed. What sould I do?

Comment: hey. did u find the solution. i currently have the same issue :(